# Format for Return URL for PDT in PayPal

Tags: paypal, eclipse-pdt

I have a Business Site and am using Sandbox to try to get PDT to work.

I set up return URL in selling preferences and turned PDT ON - but my Sandbox buyers do not get returned to the site.

There are warnings that if you do not format the return url properly then it will not work, but I cannot find any instruction as to what that format is. I am not sure if I specify the page I want to return to or just the root address which PayPal will something to.

I want to use it with an https, but I have also tried and failed with a different http site that I have.

Can you suggest what I might have forgotten to do?

It would be great if you could help me get started on this fairly fundamental point!

Comment: Do you have Auto-Return enabled along with PDT in the sandbox seller account that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

We have multiple sites that uses PayPal standard with PDT and IPN callbacks, when I switch this to sandbox mode things don't work but works outside of the sandbox. Try connecting to the live urls and see if that works, you can always refund payments if they go through.

In the posting url you can specify `&return=XXX` where XXX is the url encoded url back to your site
[This will override the setting within PayPal which is handy if you have multiple sites using the same PayPal account]

You can also specify the IPN (which should also be implemented) using `&notify_url=`

Comment: Testing will work just fine in the sandbox as long as you have everything configured correctly.  I never recommend testing on the live servers.

Comment: OK -thanks for taking the trouble to help out. Looks like I might have to try it live to see if Mark is right. If it doesn't work there, then clearly I have the wrong configuration somewhere as Andrew suggests.... do I use the complete path to the page I want - or just the root url?

Comment: You should use absolute/full paths back to the PDT and IPN.

Comment: @ Andrew Angell: I agree, however in my case, it works with live urls and not in sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

I got an auto-return to work in the sandbox!

Not quite sure what I did BUT it might have been that I set up PDT and IPN in the sandbox site, instead of just in the live site.

thanks for replies. I am not out of the woods yet, but I now live in hope.